# How to deploy or package a maven plugin after building a maven-plugin project?

Tags: maven-2, maven-plugin

I have done an `mvn install` for a custom plugin and it gave me a bunch of directories in my target directory along with a jar. I'm stuck with the next step.
How do I bundle it?
Where do I place this?
What about the pom of this plugin?
What configuration changes do I have to make and where?

Comment: Do you have a repository to which you can upload it?

Comment: Should this plugin be used inside your company or for others outside into the wild? You need to have a repository to put that plugin into...usually you will do such things via mvn release:prepare and mvn release:perform...

Comment: I do have an internal repository but before I can upload it there I must make sure that it does what it says. Can I not test it on my local machine? This is for a POC purpose only so needs to be within the company.

Answer (score 1):

You can always test it on your local machine. Just run `mvn clean install` and it will be installed in your local repository. Then in the project you'd like to use it from, just add the plugin to the plugins section and set it up like any other plugin. This should be enough.

If you'll be using it in your company, you'll need to be able to deploy it to a Maven repository such as Nexus or Artifactory in order for other people to be able to download it.

Deploying it is the same as for regular artifacts:

```
mvn clean deploy
```